# v8 - Crash in HeapObject::GetHeap() - uninitialized value

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

From JS i call a C++-function like this:

```
var req = new IO.HttpRequest(IO.RequestType.get);
req.data({ i: 'jTKvNf9w' }).send('http://pastebin.com/raw.php', function (content) { console.log(content); });
```

The request gets processed asynchronously and once its done the callback gets invoked. In C++ the send-function looks like this:

```
void XmlHttpRequest::open(const Utils::String& str, ::JS::FunctionObjPtr callback) {
    mCallback = callback;
    mRequest->open(str);
}
```

And later if the request is completed:

```
void XmlHttpRequest::onComplete(Utils::String content) {
    sUIMgr->getDispatcher()->pushFrame(Gl::Dispatcher::Priority::Low, [this, content]() {
        ::JS::FunctionObjPtr f = mCallback;
        f->callVoid(content);
    });
}
```

The push frame puts the function in a queue to be executed in the main thread where all the scripting is set up.

Now the problem is in `callVoid` i get an access violation when HeapObject::GetHeap() calls `MemoryChunk::FromAddress(reinterpret_cast<Address>(this))->heap();`. These are v8 functions. The problem is, that the `this`-Pointer in HeapObject is 0xCCCCCCCC which means that its an uninitialized value. The `this`-Pointer comes from the handle stored in the JS::FunctionObjPtr (a typedef for std::shared_ptr).

At first i thought that there is something wrong with my `FunctionObj`. I obtain this by:

```
template<typename T>
static TYPE_RET(FunctionObjPtr) ObjectWrap::unwrap(v8::Handle<v8::Value>& value) {
    if (value->IsFunction() == false) {
        TYPE_ERR("Value is not a function");
    }

    return std::make_shared<FunctionObj>(value);
}
```

TYPE_RET is merely doing some template metaprogramming stuff. The `FunctionObj` looks like this:

```
class FunctionObj
{
    v8::Handle<v8::Value> mHandle;

public:
    FunctionObj(v8::Handle<v8::Value>& fun) {
        mHandle = fun;
    }

    FunctionObj() { }

    operator bool () {
        return mHandle.IsEmpty() == false;
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    void callVoid(const Args&... args) {
        std::vector<v8::Handle<v8::Value>> arguments;
        addArgument(arguments, args...);

        v8::TryCatch tc;
        v8::Handle<v8::Function>::Cast(mHandle)->Call(mHandle, arguments.size(), arguments.data());
        if (tc.HasCaught()) {
            throw JS::Exception(tc.Exception(), tc.StackTrace());
        }
    }
};
```

When I call the function in `XmlHttpRequest::open` where its 'registered' it works. So at first i thought that the object gets gc'ed, but in order to make sure it wont ever get collected in FunctionObj::FunctionObj i created a v8::Persistent from the handle. Still it crashes. I even made the v8::Persistent weak to have a look if it really gets collected, but the weak callback never gets called.

Other things I have checked right before the call:

1. v8::Isolate::GetCurrent() -> Returns the correct, entered isolate
2. v8::Context::GetCurrent() -> Same
3. The global HandleScope is not left
4. XmlHttpRequest::open and the lambda with the call are called in the same thread

Further information:
This is not restricted to v8::Handle<v8::Function> only. It also happens if I try to store an object and access one of its properties later. I just cant to anything inside that lambda that uses a handle.

Comment: Don't know if this helps but if you store object and want to access its properties later try to use Persistent pointer type. e.g.
Persistent<Object> module_handle = Persistent<Object>::New(target);

Comment: It helped. It was not directly the cause of the problem directly (as ive tried the persistent solution already) but it kept me going on the persistent trail which was the right way to go, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As I have said in the things I've tried I had a look at `v8::Persistent`. Turns out I used it wrong.

**What I did:**

```
class FunctionObj
{
    v8::Handle<v8::Value> mHandle;
    v8::Persistent<v8::Value> mPersistent;
public:
    FunctionObj(v8::Handle<v8::Value>& fun) {
        mPersistent.Reset(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), fun);
        mHandle = fun;
    }

    FunctionObj() { }

    operator bool () {
        return mHandle.IsEmpty() == false;
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    void callVoid(const Args&... args) {
        std::vector<v8::Handle<v8::Value>> arguments;
        addArgument(arguments, args...);

        v8::TryCatch tc;
        v8::Handle<v8::Function>::Cast(mHandle)->Call(mHandle, arguments.size(), arguments.data());
        if (tc.HasCaught()) {
            throw JS::Exception(tc.Exception(), tc.StackTrace());
        }
    }
};
```

**What I should have done**

```
class FunctionObj
{
    v8::Persistent<v8::Value> mPersistent;
public:
    FunctionObj(v8::Handle<v8::Value>& fun) {
        mPersistent.Reset(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), fun);
    }

    FunctionObj() { if(mPersistent) { mPersistent.Dispose(); } }

    operator bool () {
        return mHandle.IsEmpty() == false;
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    void callVoid(const Args&... args) {
        std::vector<v8::Handle<v8::Value>> arguments;
        addArgument(arguments, args...);

        v8::Local<v8::Function> fun = v8::Local<v8::Function>::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), mPersistent.As<v8::Function>());

        v8::TryCatch tc;
        fun->Call(fun, arguments.size(), arguments.data());
        if (tc.HasCaught()) {
            throw JS::Exception(tc.Exception(), tc.StackTrace());
        }
    }
};
```

The persistent i created does not mean that the handle i stored does not get destroyed but only that it will later be possible to query a new handle to the object and that the object wont be deleted.

Now all works like a charm!